# Прочитать файл от условия до условия

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Есть данные:

```
time timezone 120 
time daylight-time-rule Western-Europe 
ip access-list extended "test" 
   строка
   строка
   exit 
ip access-list extended "test2" 
    строка
    строка
exit

ip access-list extended "test3" 
    строка
    строка
exit
```

Задача состоит в том что нужно распарсить блок начиная от "ip access-list extended "test" "  до строчки exit

У меня получилось только с одним условием, т.е парсить от ip access-list extended "test"  и до конца. Подскажите как сделать условие выхода по строке "Exit"

Код

```
with open("File", "r") as file:

   for line in file:
       if 'ip access-list extended "from_wifi"' in line:
           print(file.read())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` является итератором над строками в Питоне. Особенность итераторов, что они расходуются при чтении, поэтому строки не будут прочитаны дважды:

```
from itertools import takewhile

for line in file:
    if line.startswith("ip access-list extended"):
        access_list = ''.join(takewhile(lambda line: line.strip() != "exit", file))
```

Данный код читает файл строчка за строчкой пока не встретится блок с access-list. Затем все строки—до тех пор пока строка равная `exit` не встретится—считаются принадлежащими текущему access-list блоку. После этого цикл продолжается и читаются оставшиеся блоки до конца файла.

Если файл маленький, то можно с помощью регулярного выражения все access-list блоки сразу получить:

```
import re

text = file.read()
access_lists = re.findall(r"ip access-list extended\s+(.*?)\s+^\s*exit\s*$", text,
                          flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Результат для ввода в вопросе:

```
['"test" \n   строка\n   строка',
 '"test2" \n    строка\n    строка',
 '"test3" \n    строка\n    строка']
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны два варианта:

1. Использовать методы **readline** или **readlines** для построчного чтения файла, или
2. Загружаем файл целиком в строку и ищем индексы начала и конца той его части которая нам нужна с помощью методов **find** или **index**. Далее получаем нужную часть срезом и с ней работаем.